# Как их "толкать" при наведение мыши?

Tags: javascript, jquery

У меня есть блоки. Как их "толкать" при наведение мыши.
То есть при наведение на один из блоков он отталкивается на 100px в зависимости от направления прилёта мыши.
Любая идея либо даже код jquery будет меня радовать.

```css
#wrapper-box4 {
  width: 94.01%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: #444;
}

#box-content1 div, 
#box-content2 div, 
#box-content3 div{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #888;
  border: 1px dashed #fcfcfc;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 40px;
}

#box-content1, #box-content2, #box-content3 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

```html
  <div id="wrapper-box4">
    <div id="box-content1">
      <div class="box-item1">1</div>
      <div class="box-item2">2</div>
      <div class="box-item3">3</div>
      <div class="box-item4">4</div>
    </div>
    <div id="box-content2">
      <div class="box-item5">5</div>
      <div class="box-item6">6</div>
      <div class="box-item7">7</div>
      <div class="box-item8">8</div>
    </div>
    <div id="box-content3">
      <div class="box-item9">9</div>
      <div class="box-item10">10</div>
      <div class="box-item11">11</div>
      <div class="box-item12">12</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: я бы копал в сторону 2d physics js engine и RigidBody

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте [Parallax.js](http://matthew.wagerfield.com/parallax/). Или любую другую параллакс библиотеку. Можете конечно и вручную попробовать сделать, но если вы слабо знакомы с jQuery то будет сложновато.

Из базового для собственного скрипта вам нужно понять что такое ивенты JavaScript. Наведение курсора поверх блока это ивент блока `:hover` или jQuery `.mouseover()`. Ну а двигать блок можно разными вариантами, можно сделать его абсолютным и изменять `top, left ...`, а можно изменять `transform: translate()` и так далее.

Советую начать работать над скриптом(использованием библиотеки или же вручную) самому и заходить сюда за помощью в непонятных моментах. Таким образом вы чего-то научитесь сами, а не просто скопируете чей-то скрипт(если конечно кто-то напишет его для вас).

Comment: Дак это и так понятно. Прикол в тому как рандомно высчитать отступ и его значения а также при анимации плавной кинуть блок на начальное место....

Comment: Дак это и так понятно. Главное понять как рандомно научить думать скрипт координаты margin и потом назад плавное возвращать

Comment: @Виталий Слободянюк что значит рандомно? Для рандома есть `Math.random`, для движения я перечислил варианты: `transform: translate()`, `margin`, `top`, `left`... Для плавности движения используйте `transition`. Информацию по любому слову тут можно найти за 2 секунды в гугле.

Comment: Хорошо, а теперь вместе это всё свяжи ))))